# Mingw Could be found

Tags: c++

I am using Ubuntu. This is file i wanted to compile but i am getting error out of it. I was trying to get mingw-w64 as dependency for a software and from now on i am getting this error every time  I compile my codes which were working yesterday.

Note : Code is fine and was working as normal till yesterday until i tried to install mingw-w64 which also failed.[Compilation of a cpp file which was working before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO4M5.png)

Comment: Obviously you need to fix your installation of mingw-w64. I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: I had installed mingw-w64 it but it was also failing to do so. I could only configure its tar.gz file which also gave error and after that i was getting error in compiling my C++ files as Win32 only supported. Then i deleted mingw files from usr/local/include and got this error afterwards.

Comment: MinGW is for Windows, not Linux. If you want some [cross-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler), please mention it. Linux and Windows are different OSes.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61495615/edit) your question to provide an [MRE]. A compilation command with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) should be like `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` since you want all warnings and debug info

Comment: Indeed But i was installing it as a dependency for some other software but ended up loosing configuration for my c++ which had no concern with that.

Comment: Consider sharing your C++ code on [github](https://github.com/), and show in your question both your compilation command, some C++ code, and the *exact* error message you get (as text, not as an image)

Comment: If no method works for you and you get irritated and wants to start coding, just execute: `apt install gcc && apt install gcc-c++` as sudo. Peace.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling mingw? It looks like you have a header file either missing from the path variable, or it got corrupted.

Edit: Also, it looks like you are trying to include it. Make sure that is the path that mingw.h is in.

Comment: I had installed it but it was also failing to do so. I could only configure its tar.gz file which also gave error and after that it was giving error like Win32 only supported. Then i deleted mingw files from usr/local/include and got this error afterwards.

Comment: deleteing the mingw files was obviously a mistake. Just uninstall everything mingw related and start again.

Comment: unfortunately removing it gives a message that i have nothing like mingw-w64 in Ubuntu.